# How to handle ReportViewerWebPart report printing error?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, reporting-services

I’m implementing a solution based on SharePoint 2010 and MS Reporting Server. I’m experiencing a problem with ReportViewerWepPart. I have a scenario where I need to display a custom error when a report cannot be printed. Unfortunately, unlike ReportViewer asp control, ReportViewerWepPart does not have any properties/events indicating that there is an error and the report cannot be printed. After spending some time on the problem I came with a solution using reflection. I discovered that ReportViewerWepPart uses internally ReportViewer and I attached to ReportError event on this private internal component. Here is my code:

```
…
            try
            {
                ReportViewer rv = (reportViewer.GetType().GetField("m_reportViewer", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(reportViewer) as ReportViewer);
                rv.ReportError += new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportErrorEventHandler(ReportWidgetControl_ReportError);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                LogHandler.LogError(e, "Unable to attach ReportViewerWebPart error hadler.");
            }
…
        void ReportWidgetControl_ReportError(object sender, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            reportViewer.Visible = false;
            HandleError();
        }
```

Unfortunately this solution is a hack in the web part. Do you think that using a reflection in that way can cause any problems? Am I missing something, Is there another way to see if report is printed?

Answer (score 0):

This is fine, but I would be careful catching all exceptions.
It looks like you are hiding the reportViewer and calling your HandleError code no matter what the error. There may be exceptions that occur that are minor and are handled without issue internally and hiding the reportViewer object might not be appropriate. 
I don't know what your HandleError code does but I would suggest quietly logging the error to a log table or file until you spot the exact printing error you are trying to handle, and then only worrying about handling that.